# fail to install ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics

Tags: ros, package, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 14.04, ros indigo

It seems like something exists in multiple packages.
How to fix it?
[image: image description]

shawn@evashawn:/opt/ros/indigo/share$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 533 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/131 kB of archives.
After this operation, 687 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 282423 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics_0.7.8-0trusty-20170328-004135-0700_amd64.deb ...
**Unpacking ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics (0.7.8-0trusty-20170328-004135-0700) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics_0.7.8-0trusty-20170328-004135-0700_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/srv_kinematics_plugin/srv_kinematics_plugin.h', which is also in package ros-indigo-moveit-ros-planning 0.7.2-0trusty-20161115-195213-0800
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)**
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics_0.7.8-0trusty-20170328-004135-0700_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260919/fail-to-install-ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First try sudo apt-get update/upgrade then do installation. Hope this will help.

---

Originally posted by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) with karma: 49 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-05-03**:
I try to sudo apt-get -f upgrade, and then it works. Thanks.
But I wonder does forcing to upgrade cause some compatible problems afterwards?